# Can C++ be used as back-end and Javafx as front-end in the same Application?

Tags: java, c++, user-interface, exe

Can C++ be used as back-end and Javafx as front-end in the same Application?

And if I do this will the application be an executable (*.exe) ? Otherwise is there any way to make it an Executable (*.exe) ?

**Edit: Reason - I've got some problem in developing GUI applications with C++. **

Comment: but why?????????

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response; I've got some problem to make GUI applications with C++

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ mixing C++ with Java is a usually a bad idea but writing a desktop application in C++ alone/ Java alone is not a bad option

Comment: @SamarthSaxena wouldn't is be a better idea to just overcome your "C++ GUI problems"?

Comment: Then do you know any way other than using Qt to develop GUI applications with C++ ?

Comment: You mention .exe so I assume you are running Windows, in which case, what about MFC for the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a server/client system, where the server is C++ and the client is Java, communicating with some sort of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) between them.  Once there is a disconnect between components, they can be any combination of languages.  I'm currently working on a system, where the front end is C# (GUI) and the back end is VB.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a GUI is about **displaying** information. There is no rule that says that **processing** and **displaying** needs to happen in the same application; written in the same language.

In other words: you "only" need an abstraction layer that allows you to retrieve data from the C++; and to use services on the side.

Your C++ side could provide a RESTful API; or you use JNI to make native calls. Various possibilities, but all of that: **advanced** topics.

Comment: Which extension will it hold? *.exe or *.jar... Coz I want it to be *.exe..... or even better to have it cross platform....

Comment: The java part comes as .jar, the C++ as binary. But honestly: I think you are overburdening yourself here. Yes, all of this is possible, but it is an **advanced** task to get there. When you already struggle to understand such details ... I fear you wont get very far

Comment: Thanks man; Then do you know any way other than using Qt to develop GUI applications with C++ ?

Comment: Don't get into the comment/question ping pong please. Even for c++ there would be various options, but well: those might have dependencies on the underlying OS! So you need to clarify your requirements upfront (and just for the record: "which framework to use" is an offtopic question here)